# EditText does not display properly in landscape mode when displayed from UI implementing a Service

Tags: android, android-edittext, landscape

[image]

I have an application that locks the phone. Implemented Lock screen UI using Service so that user can not access other features of phone if phone is locked. There is an unlock password dialog for entering password to unlock the phone.

The problem is with the edittext of the dialog. In landscape mode it does not look properly.The edittext should become fullscreen with the soft keypad at the bottom.

Pls help.!

Comment: Have you tried "`match_parent`" as width and height of `editText` ?

Comment: yes, have tried that. still not working..

Answer (score 3):

You need to add android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" to prevent this behavior.